# How to set kendoTooltip custom width with function?

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to kendo tooltip custom width:

here is my code:

```
$(".tooptip_labell").kendoTooltip({
  position: "right",
   animation: {
      open: {
        effects: "fade:in"
        }}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add 'width: 500' to your configuration. In your case it should be like below(I set its value as 150px.You may change that into whatever you want.)

```
$(".tooptip_labell").kendoTooltip({
     position: "right",
     width:150,
     animation: {
     open: {
         effects: "fade:in"
    }}});
```